# Server's chain certificate verification failed in azure Client

Tags: c, azure-sdk, sslv3, tls1.0, threadx

I am trying to run my IoT-client on Threadx-Os Client which doesn't have file- system/certificate trusted store kind of things like in linux. When i look into Wireshark the client closing connection with Fatal,Bad certificate error. I tried all possible options which are suggested in different forums to solve this issue. Which haven't solved my problem. The solution i tried mentioned below.

By using below API to added only above Baltimore root certificate available in cert.c.

> IoTHubDeviceClient_LL_SetOption(device_ll_handle, OPTION_TRUSTED_CERT,
>   certificates);

```
it's not working for me because we don't have trusted store like linux.
```

> ## ifdef SET_TRUSTED_CERT_IN_SAMPLES
>
> ```
>     // Setting the Trusted Certificate.  This is only necessary on system with without
>     // built in certificate stores.
>         IoTHubDeviceClient_LL_SetOption(device_ll_handle, OPTION_TRUSTED_CERT, certificates);
> ```
>
> ## endif // SET_TRUSTED_CERT_IN_SAMPLES

```
I need answers for two important questions.
```

1)  Do i need to Add entire certificate string in cert.c (or) only first Baltimore root as CA root to my client.

2) Without trusted store, how client can  tell to azure-cloud i have trusted root.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I found the problem , Client can not able to decode server chain certificate properly. With minute change in ssl code we get rid of it. Thank you.

Comment: Hi,you could summarize your word as an answer for others' reference,thanks!

Comment: We are currently using treck SSL , in one the function the server chain certificate is decoding one by one . We got failure while 2nd certificate decode. it's throwing unexpected signature and algorithm values. We bypass it. It's working fine.